# Runtime Error 424 - Text Property in Range object

Tags: vba, excel

I am a VBA beginner, so the below is likely to be a basic step that I've missed.

When trying to edit the Text property of the Range method , I keep getting

> Runtime error 424 , object required.

e.g. for the below code:

```
Range("A1").Text = "ABC"
```

Is this a case of setting the range?

Comment: Text is a readonly property use `.Value` instead of `.Text`

Comment: Can't write to a read-only property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-text-property-excel  However, this probably should be raising a 1004 error, not a 424 Object Required.

Comment: @DavidZemens Just tried it as a single line sub, it returned the 424 error.  I also would have assumed the 1004 error.

Comment: I did the same thing @ScottCraner, definitely a weird error to raise in this circumstance. Interestingly, if you do `[A1].Text = "foo"` you *will* get a proper 1004: "Unable to set the Text property of the Range class"

Answer (score 4):

The run-time error "424 Object Required" is explainable, and believe it or not, actually makes sense.

`Range.Text` is read-only, so you can't assign to it; arguably there should be a compile-time error complaining about the assignment attempt, such as:

> Invalid use of property

Or

> Can't assign to read-only property

However, because `Range.Text` returns a `Variant` and not a `String`, and the property is get-only, VBA assumes the assignment is legal, and that the property will be returning a `Variant/Object`, where the `Object` has a *default property* that *can* be assigned.

So assigning this property in `Sheet1`'s code-behind:

```
Public Property Get Foo() As String
    Foo = "FOO"
End Property
```

Is a compile-time *can't assign to read-only property* error.

But this:

```
Public Property Get Foo() As Variant
    Foo = "FOO"
End Property
```

Is a run-time *object required* error - because for the assignment to be legal, the `Property Get` function is *expected* to return an *object*. And when it doesn't, then *object required* makes total sense.

Consider this:

```
Public Property Get Foo() As Range
    Set Foo = ActiveCell
End Property
```

This property is just as read-only as any of the above: you cannot legally re-assign the reference `Foo` is returning.

But this is totally legal:

```
Sheet1.Foo = 42
```

And, in fact, implicit code for this:

```
Sheet1.Foo().Value = 42
```

So the assignment is assigning to the write-enabled, *default property* of the returned object reference.

And this reference assignment:

```
Set Sheet1.Foo = ActiveCell
```

Is a compile-time *invalid use of property*, because `Foo` doesn't expose a `Set` accessor.

This is indeed very confusing for beginners. Ironically, VB6/VBA exposing *default properties* was supposed to "make it easier" for beginners.